# Find the time complexity of the given code

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, computer-science

Although this is a computer science question,still i am posting it here because it needs loads of mathematics in it.

### Question

Find the time complexity of the given code-:

```
While(n>2)
{ 
  n=n/log(2,n);
}
```

### My Approach

The series of the code can be written as-:

$$S=\frac{n}{\log_{2}n}+\frac{n}{\log_{2}^{2}n}+\frac{n}{\log_{2}^{3}n}+...\frac{n}{\log_{2}^{k}n}$$
$$=n(\frac{1}{\log_{2}n}+\frac{1}{\log_{2}^{2}n}+\frac{1}{\log_{2}^{3}n}+...\frac{1}{\log_{2}^{k}n})$$

now i have to solve

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{i=k}\log_2 ^{i}n $$

---

totally stucked to move forward.please help.

---

[EDIT]
i need to find $k$,

$$\frac{n}{\log_{2}^{k}n}=2$$

$$\frac{n}{\log_{2}^{k}n}=2$$

Comment: The series $S$ is completely irrelevant. The time complexity of this algorithm is $k$, where $k$ is the number of traversals of the main loop.

Comment: i am not getting how to solve $k$

Comment: Your description seems inconsistent to me. The `while(n>2)` clause together with `=` symbol suggest you _modify_ `n` each step (the `while` would be ineffective otherwise), but the sum expansion suggests you assume `n` in numerators being _constant_.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Comment: @HansHüttel unable to figure out your given hint.can you please help!